# Consumir Web Service .NET desde SQL enviando parámetros string

Tags: sql, .net, webservice

Trato de enviar data a un WS el cual tiene un método llamado "Agregar", método al cual le tengo que enviar el parámetro "xmlString" con un string, y sí todo anda bien me devuelve un parámetro de respuesta "AgregarResult" con la respuesta de success o fail.

Al conectarme al WS desde PHP anda todo perfecto, pero necesito conectarme desde **SQL SERVER 2008** al WS y lo estoy haciendo como se muestra en la foto, y obtengo una respuesta que es:

> "Falta el elemento Raíz".

Supongo que se refiere a la variable que espera el método del WS y también supongo que la conexión desde el SQL funciona ya que por lo menos tengo un error.

Mi consulta es:

- ¿En que parte del código SQL debo invocar el método del WS?
- ¿Donde y cómo le envío el parámetro con el string al WS?

Se agradece la ayuda.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @sUrl varchar(max);
Declare @xmlString varchar (8000);
Declare @largo varchar (max);
Declare @SOAPAction varchar (max)

SET @xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<Agregar xmlns="http://qa.in-touch.cl/">
    <xmlString>
        <![CDATA[ 
        <Cliente>
                <Identificador>'+@Concesionario+'</Identificador> 
                <IdCotizacion>'+@IdCotizacion+'</IdCotizacion>
                <IdNegocio>'+@IdNegocio+'</IdNegocio>
                <FhoCreacion>'+@FhoCreacion+'</FhoCreacion>
                <Rut>'+@Rut+'</Rut>
                <Nombre>'+@Nombre+' Andres</Nombre>
                <ApPaterno>'+@ApPaterno+'</ApPaterno>
                <ApMaterno>'+@ApMaterno+'</ApMaterno>
                <Telefono>'+@Telefono+'</Telefono>
                <Email>'+@Email+'</Email>
                <FechaNac>'+@FechaNac+'</FechaNac>
                <Genero>'+@Genero+'</Genero>
                <IndVehPropio>'+@IndVehPropio+'</IndVehPropio>                   
           <CodMarcaVehPropio>'+@CodMarcaVehPropio+'</CodMarcaVehPropio> 
        <CodModeloVehPropio>'+@CodModeloVehPropio+'</CodModeloVehPropio>
                <AnoVehPropio>'+@AnoVehPropio+'</AnoVehPropio>
                <ChkVehLista>'+@ChkVehLista+'</ChkVehLista>
                <TxtMarca>'+@TxtMarca+'</TxtMarca>
                <TxtModelo>'+@TxtModelo+'</TxtModelo> 
                <TxtAnoVehDos>'+@TxtAnoVehDos+'</TxtAnoVehDos>
                <CodMarcaDitec>'+@CodMarcaDitec+'</CodMarcaDitec>
                <CodEstiloDitec>'+@CodEstiloDitec+'</CodEstiloDitec>
                <CodModeloDitec>'+@CodModeloDitec+'</CodModeloDitec> 
                <CodSucursal>'+@CodSucursal+'</CodSucursal>
                <CodVendedor>'+@CodVendedor+'</CodVendedor>                  
           <IndFinanciamiento>'+@IndFinanciamiento+'</IndFinanciamiento>
                <Pie>'+@Pie+'</Pie>
                <Cuotas>'+@Cuotas+'</Cuotas>
                <Observaciones>'+@Observaciones+'</Observaciones>
                <CodOrigen>'+@CodOrigen+'</CodOrigen>
                <Concesionario>'+@Concesionario+' CD</Concesionario>
                <UsuarioCreador>'+@UsuarioCreador+'</UsuarioCreador>
            </Cliente>
            ]]>
        </xmlString>
    </Agregar>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'

SET @largo = LEN(@xmlString)
SET @sUrl = 'http://landing.in-touch.cl/wsditec/carga.asmx?WSDL'
SET @SOAPAction = 'http://qa.in-touch.cl/Agregar'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl,'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Host'           
,'landing.in-touch.cl'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Type'   
,'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Length' , 
@largo
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'SOAPAction'     , 
@SOAPAction
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'                ,NULL, @xmlString
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Saludos!!

Comment: Bienvenido Ricardo, de preferencia que el codigo se en texto no una imagen, es mas facil ayudarte así

Comment: Hola, estás seguro que el parámetro `?WSDL` es necesario?

Comment: hey bro! ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Para contestar tus dos preguntas la **primera** después del Declare tienes que hacer un Set a la variable url te quedaría asi:

```
@sUrl ='http://landing.in-touch.cl/ws/Carga.asmx?WSDL/Parametro1='+@Parametro''

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST',@sUrl,'false'
```

Este seria el otro cambio

Esta variable @Parametro la tienes que haber declarado en tu procedimiento almacenado

Para ejecutarlo como es un procedimiento almacenado

```
EXEC nombreDelProcediminto 'el parametro'
```

Comment: Lo realicé tal cual me comentas, pero no me funciona, me retorna un NULL, agregue una nueva respuesta, estuve leyendo más información y creo que tengo un avance pero de arroja el error que menciono en la respuesta (La escribí como respuesta por la cantidad de caracteres) @RaulCacacho

Comment: Pero ese error es porque como estas haciendo un update algun campo de los que envias va nulo y en la base de datos le tienes que no sea nulo

Comment: Lo raro es que desde PHP lo logró enviar sin ningún problema, con exactamente los mismos campos :/

Comment: y el id de la tabla puede ser lo tienes autoincrementable?

Comment: Si, es autoincrementable. Volví a ejecutar el código en el PHP y funciona impecable. Me voy a matar!! Jajjajaja

Comment: Puedes verificar que todos los campos lleguen ws con la información que enviaste

Answer (score -1):

Agrega el elemento

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

a tu xml. Ese es el elemento raíz.

```
<xmlString>
    <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Cliente>
            <Identificador>'+@Concesionario+'</Identificador> 
            <IdCotizacion>'+@IdCotizacion+'</IdCotizacion>
```

Comment: esto ya se esta agregando, lo indica en la pregunta :  SET @xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>